# Can't reference an utterence file in botium

Tags: chatbot

I am new to botium and my developer (not me) has created a framework with conversation text files that I should be able to run botium scripts on.

An example is something like this:

```
#me
What are the stats for my neighborhood?

#bot
There are ten matches in your neighborhood
```

When I run this test in my IDE, it passes. So, I created a text file called NEIGHBORHOOD_UTT which has sentences similar to the following:

What are the stats for my neighborhood
Show me neighborhood stats
Neighborhood

And then changed my convo.txt file to:

```
#me
NEIGHBORHOOD_UTT

#bot
There are ten matches in your neighborhood
```

All these I've tested on the app through the GUI and should return "There are ten matches in your neighborhood"

The error is something like: TranscriptError: BotiumError: neighborhood/Line 6: Expected bot response (on Line 3:
 #me - NEIGHBORHOOD_UTT) "Sorry, I couldn't find any listings for" to match one of "There are ten matches in your neighborhood."

The GUI is not responding with "Sorry, I couldn't find any listings", but the expected response. There is no API documentation for me to check there. I can't share too much as this is work/proprietary. Both the utterences and the convo txt are in a folder called botium

I have tried naming the file both NEIGHBORHOOD_UTT.utterances.txt and NEIGHBORHOOD_UTT.txt

I cannot think of anything else so I have searched github for random projects similar to mine and haven't found any that provided any clues

Comment: first line of an utterances file is the utterance reference code. here are examples: https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/491664/Botium+Scripting+-+BotiumScript

Comment: @FlorianTreml thanks! Please suggest as an answer so I can give you credit, this worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line of an utterances file is the utterance reference code. For example:

```
USER_HELLO_UTT
hi
hello
nice day
```

*USER_HELLO_UTT* can be used in convo files then:

```
Say hello

#me
USER_HELLO_UTT

#bot
Hi!
```

More examples available in the [Botium Wiki](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/491664/Botium+Scripting+-+BotiumScript)